# Is executing multiple PHP Scripts ran one at a time or simultaneously?

Tags: php, exec

When executing multiple scripts within PHP using the `exec` command; are each script ran one at a time as in one after the other or are they ran simultaneously?

```
exec('/usr/bin/php -q process-duplicates.php');
exec('/usr/bin/php -q process-images.php');
exec('/usr/bin/php -q process-sitemaps.php');
```

Just want to make sure they are one after the other before attempting to rewrite my crontabs.

Comment: Can someone execute this script from a HTTP request outside of cron? What happens if someone does and loads it 100 times? How quickly will the server die? Get these into a crontab, not a PHP script.

Comment: As mentioned in the answers below, it's synchronous (one at a time), however you might want to take a look at http://reactphp.org/ if you want to do asynchronous actions in PHP. In particular https://github.com/reactphp/child-process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the only way to run at background is adding & to the command line arguments, which would put that exec()'d process into the background:

```
exec("php test.php &");
```

So you are right, they run one after the other.

**NOTE:** In your case you shouldn't use `&` as it will force to run all the scripts simultaneously.

Comment: Just add & like this? exec('/usr/bin/php -q process-duplicates.php  &'); to each one? I will try that. Thanks

Comment: No, sorry if I explained wrongly, that cause to do what you dont want to do

Comment: Just make sure to DON'T use it, my apologies if I make you missunderstand

Comment: I added -- exec('php process-duplicates.php &'); and that worked perfectly. Was always under the impression -- based on what I have read online you needed the /user/bin/ path to php. Thanks for showing me that path ;)

Comment: I am happy it worked, but I cant't figure out how ;) please mark as solved in that case, you're welcomed.

Comment: Just read your other comments; as what you wrote above worked.

Comment: @JoaquinPeraza Please read up on shell scripting, the '&' on the end is telling the shell to background the process and return,

Comment: Geoffrey, exactly, that why I recommend to not use it in this case. :/

Answer (score 0):

exec waits for the script to return, see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

But as a devops, please please please do not run your cron jobs like this! Create entries in the crontab for each, or put them in a shell script and have cron run the script.

Comment: A shell script like this `shell_exec`? Sorry for asking -- I am new with PHP and working into something even newer for me! Thanks

Comment: @TopResults No worries, we are all always learning :). A shell script has nothing in common with `shell_exec`, under windows you could call a 'bat' file a shell script. On a unix/linux/mac system, a shell script is a script of commands executed by the shell, or command line, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script

Comment: Thanks again. Been reading how to make a shell script (more learning)!! If you don't mind me asking another question. Why not run cron jobs like this?

Comment: @TopResults Because you are loading a huge framework (PHP) just to launch more scripts. It wastes CPU resources, and memory.